# Implementing OCR Recognition with IOS and HTML5

Tags: html, ipad, html5-canvas, ocr

I've implemented an HTML5 generic web form solutions that allows my customer to create surveys online and them deploy them offline to their Ipads. They can collect data with or without internet access, and then push back to the Surveys server the collected data once the internet connection is available again.

The forms are also able to take pictures, store them locally on the Ipads, and then push them to the server.

My customer is now asking me if we can figure out a way to do OCR recognition on business cards to fullfill the forms quickly (first name, last name, adress, company & phone).

I've been investigating OCRAD.js but the result is not positive.[Click to see the sceen capture result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qlQN.png)
Does anybody knows another HTML 5 alternative? Could I communicate with a real APP to do the OCR recognition an retrieve the data?

Please advice.

Comment: In practice, business card OCR is difficult to do because business cards often include artwork, multiple font styles, non-contrasting text, in-exact text due to raised lettering and scanning misalignment. We don't do software library recommendations here on Stackoverflow, but you will almost certainly need to test a variety of 3rd party apps to get your desire result.

Comment: Thanks mark, however the big question is: can I achieve such a functionality in pure HTML5 with standard tools....?

Comment: We don't do software library recommendations here on Stackoverflow, but you will almost certainly need to test a variety of 3rd party apps to get your desire result.